# Powershell import-csv

Tags: powershell, import-csv

Creating a script that checks if a list of users from csv file are in a specific AD Group

```html
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$userscsv = Import-Csv C:\User-list.csv 
$group = "testgroup"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach ($user in $userscsv) {
    If ($members -contains $user) {
      Write-Host "$user exists in the group"
 } Else {
      Write-Host "$user does not exists in the group"
}}​
```

In my csv file i have the names in A1 A2 A# etc I get this format bellow:

```
@{Johnny Walker=Alex Hood} does not exists in the group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
$userscsv = Import-Csv C:\User-list.csv | select -ExpandProperty User
```

It worked, if you guys have some feedback and tweaking, I'm all ears

Comment: Well it appears the user name you are checking is in the csv file stored in the column named `user`. By using `Select -Expandproperty user` you pulled the values from that column into a string array. That works because in the loop you are now checking a string array for the presents of a string (user name in an array of usernames). Well done I say!